# How to use OAuth2 with my own auth server?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I don't really have an app now but I am curious.

Website KK has their own account login and can also login with FB, Github, etc.

How should KK manage the authentication with KK account and Facebook account?

It's really weird if KK login needs permission from itself like this.

KK App will has permission to *permission here* with your KK account. Continue?

Comment: I don't have any code examples, just an opinion. It's not the most efficient model to use OAuth for your own site. There's a lot of stress to OAuth and ultimately it just leads back to a password box. You could just take out all that middle steps. Remember also OAuth only gets you authentication. Once they're in they still need to be authorized and tracked in some way, like cookies or JWT.

Comment: @BinaryPatrick I think I don't really understand OAuth and how it works